# Dividing and aggregating intervals into buckets

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am successfully using PostgreSQL `width_bucket(val, min, max, buckets)` function to divide my dataset into equal-sized buckets. But my data contains time ranges in milliseconds (`start_time` and `end_time`). I am looking for a way to include the row into multiple buckets based on the time interval.

This is an example of where I am now. I have start and end buckets for each row:

```
 start_time |    end_time    | start_bucket |  end_bucket 
------------+----------------+--------------+------------
       0    |      492       |     1        |      1
     404    |      580       |     1        |      1
       0    |      628       |     1        |      1
     560    |      740       |     1        |      2
     644    |      720       |     1        |      2
      24    |      160       |     1        |      1
       0    |       88       |     1        |      1
     640    |     1268       |     1        |      2
     556    |      716       |     1        |      1
       0    |     2086       |     1        |      3
```

I am looking for an aggregated result:

```
   bucket   |    count   
------------+---------------
       1    |       10      
       2    |        4      
       3    |        1
```

I know how to achieve the result if I only take the `start_time` or `end_time` **alone** into consideration. Is there a way to aggregate what I have now into the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.bucket, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(t.start_bucket, t.end_bucket) as gs(bucket)
group by gs.bucket
order by 1;
```